# Template Complex class

Tags: c++, template, classes, overloading, complex-numbers

I have created a class `Complex` which represents a complex number of any arbitrary arithmetic type. Overloads are given for the 4 common functions, addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division.

The overloads take two different template arguments so as to allow operating on complex numbers of different types together, and the `decltype(Ty_a() + Ty_b())` is used to automatically determine the return type from the template parameters. How could I improve this code?

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<
    typename Ty,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<Ty>::value, int>::type = 0
>
class Complex
{
public:
    Complex() = default;
    Complex(const Ty &r, const Ty &i) noexcept :
        r(r), i(i)
    {}

    Ty real() const noexcept {return r;}
    Ty &real() noexcept {return r;}
    Ty imag() const noexcept {return i;}
    Ty &imag() noexcept {return i;}
private:
    Ty r, i;
};

template<typename Ty_a, typename Ty_b>
Complex<decltype(Ty_a() + Ty_b())> operator+ (const Complex<Ty_a> &a, const Complex<Ty_b> &b) noexcept
{
    return {a.real() + b.real(), a.imag() + b.imag()};
}

template<typename Ty_a, typename Ty_b>
Complex<decltype(Ty_a() - Ty_b())> operator- (const Complex<Ty_a> &a, const Complex<Ty_b> &b) noexcept
{
    return {a.real() - b.real(), a.imag() - b.imag()};
}

template<typename Ty_a, typename Ty_b>
Complex<decltype(Ty_a() * Ty_b())> operator* (const Complex<Ty_a> &a, const Complex<Ty_b> &b) noexcept
{
    typedef decltype(Ty_a() * Ty_b()) result_t;
    result_t real = a.real() * b.real() - a.imag() * b.imag();
    result_t imag = a.real() * b.imag() + b.real() * a.imag();
    return {real, imag};
}

template<typename Ty_a, typename Ty_b>
Complex<decltype(Ty_a() / Ty_b())> operator/ (const Complex<Ty_a> &a, const Complex<Ty_b> &b) noexcept
{
    typedef decltype(Ty_a() / Ty_b()) result_t;
    result_t denominator = b.real() * b.real() + b.imag() * b.imag();
    result_t real = (a.real() * b.real() + a.imag() * b.imag()) / denominator;
    result_t imag = (a.imag() * b.real() - a.real() * b.imag()) / denominator;
    return {real, imag};
}

template<typename Ty>
std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &stream, const Complex<Ty> &num)
{
    return stream << num.real() << '+' << num.imag() << 'i';
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Complex<double> a(1.2, 2.25);
    Complex<int> b(2, -1);
    
    Complex<double> y = a / b;

    std::cout << y << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What does this do that `std::complex` doesn't?

Comment: @TobySpeight e.g., mixed complex types arithmetic

Answer (score 1):

##### Is encapsulation useful?

There's an important question to ask about this class: is there any benefit to keeping the data members private? As a thought experiment, how would the following `struct` be used differently than what you wrote?

```cpp
template<
    typename Ty,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<Ty>::value, int>::type = 0
>
struct Complex
{
    Ty real, imag;
};
```

1. Instead of `Complex<double> a(1.2, 2.25)`, you would write `Complex<double> a{1.2, 2.25}`.
2. Instead of `a.real()` and `a.imag()`, you would write `a.real` and `a.imag`.

In your class, the methods `Ty Complex::real() const` and `Ty& Complex::real()` (likewise for `imag()`) give complete, unrestricted access to the underlying variable. I am not saying this is a bad design. If you want the users of this class to freely modify the real and imaginary parts of the complex number, then what you wrote is correct. However, what I wrote above achieves the same result with much less code.

Effectively, you are encapsulating the innards of your `Complex` class by making the data members private and then breaking encapsulation by providing the non-`const` reference methods. Using a `struct` is simpler and achieves the same effect.

##### Making encapsulation useful

There's another way forward: make the class immutable by deleting all non-`const` methods.

```cpp
template<
    typename Ty,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<Ty>::value, int>::type = 0
>
class Complex
{
public:
    Complex() = default;
    Complex(const Ty &r, const Ty &i) noexcept :
        r(r), i(i)
    {}

    Ty real() const noexcept {return r;}
    Ty imag() const noexcept {return i;}
private:
    Ty r, i;
};
```

With this class, once a `Complex` number is created, it can never be modified. Immutable data types are easy to reason about since you never have to worry about the value of a variable changing. If the user needs a modified version of a `Complex` number, they can create a new one. Instead of

```cpp
auto z = Complex(1, 1);
// ... more code ...
z.imag() = 2;
```

users can write

```cpp
auto z = Complex(1, 1);
// ... more code ...
auto z2 = Complex(z.real(), 2);
```

One could argue that the second better expresses the intent of the programmer: "I want a `Complex` value with the real part of this other `Complex` number and an imaginary part equal to 2."

Which path you take depends on how you want the class to be used. As with most engineering questions, the correct answer is, "It depends."

##### Default Constructor

Your default constructor will leave both `r` and `i` uninitialized for the simple types of `Ty`--`int`, `double`, etc. I would delete the default constructor to force users to create a valid value for every constructed `Complex` number.

##### Templating

You've probably noticed how long the lines containing template functions can get. That's why there are helper functions for getting the `::type` and `::value` results. `std::enable_if_t<>` is equivalent to `std::enable_if<>::type` and `std::is_arithmetic_v<>` is equivalent to `std::is_arithmetic<>::value`.

```cpp
template<
    typename Ty,
    typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<Ty>, int> = 0
>
```

Although, I would state the requirement more directly using `static_assert`.

```cpp
template<typename Ty>
class Complex
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<Ty>, "Complex requires an arithmetic type.");

public:

    // etc.
};
```

##### Type juggling

In your operator overloads, you specify the return value as `Complex<decltype(Ty_a() + Ty_b())>` and similary for the other operations. A simpler name for the return type uses `std::common_type`.

```cpp
template<typename Ty_a, typename Ty_b>
Complex<std::common_type_t<Ty_a, Ty_b>> operator+ (const Complex<Ty_a>& a, const Complex<Ty_b>& b) noexcept
{
    return {a.real() + b.real(), a.imag() + b.imag()};
}
```

Now, that's a little unwieldy to repeat for all the operations, so you can declare it once and reuse it.

```cpp
template<typename Ty_a, typename Ty_b>
using op_return_type = Complex<std::common_type_t<Ty_a, Ty_b>>;

template<typename Ty_a, typename Ty_b>
op_return_type<Ty_a, Ty_b> operator+ (const Complex<Ty_a>& a, const Complex<Ty_b>& b) noexcept
{
    return {a.real() + b.real(), a.imag() + b.imag()};
}
```

##### Using `auto` to make life easier

You can use the `auto` keyword to let the compiler figure out what types should be.

```cpp
template<typename Ty_a, typename Ty_b>
op_return_type<Ty_a, Ty_b> operator/ (const Complex<Ty_a>& a, const Complex<Ty_b>& b) noexcept
{
    auto denominator = b.real() * b.real() + b.imag() * b.imag();
    auto real = (a.real() * b.real() + a.imag() * b.imag()) / denominator;
    auto imag = (a.imag() * b.real() - a.real() * b.imag()) / denominator;
    return {real, imag};
}
```

##### Putting everything together

Here's what you code looks like using all of my suggestions (using the immutable option for `Complex`):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Ty>
class Complex
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<Ty>, "Complex requires an arithmetic type.");

public:
    Complex(const Ty& r, const Ty& i) noexcept :
        r(r), i(i)
    {}

    Ty real() const noexcept { return r; }
    Ty imag() const noexcept { return i; }

private:
    Ty r, i;
};

template<typename Ty_a, typename Ty_b>
using op_return_type = Complex<std::common_type_t<Ty_a, Ty_b>>;

template<typename Ty_a, typename Ty_b>
op_return_type<Ty_a, Ty_b> operator+ (const Complex<Ty_a>& a, const Complex<Ty_b>& b) noexcept
{
    return {a.real() + b.real(), a.imag() + b.imag()};
}

template<typename Ty_a, typename Ty_b>
op_return_type<Ty_a, Ty_b> operator- (const Complex<Ty_a>& a, const Complex<Ty_b>& b) noexcept
{
    return {a.real() - b.real(), a.imag() - b.imag()};
}

template<typename Ty_a, typename Ty_b>
op_return_type<Ty_a, Ty_b> operator* (const Complex<Ty_a>& a, const Complex<Ty_b>& b) noexcept
{
    auto real = a.real() * b.real() - a.imag() * b.imag();
    auto imag = a.real() * b.imag() + b.real() * a.imag();
    return {real, imag};
}

template<typename Ty_a, typename Ty_b>
op_return_type<Ty_a, Ty_b> operator/ (const Complex<Ty_a>& a, const Complex<Ty_b>& b) noexcept
{
    auto denominator = b.real() * b.real() + b.imag() * b.imag();
    auto real = (a.real() * b.real() + a.imag() * b.imag()) / denominator;
    auto imag = (a.imag() * b.real() - a.real() * b.imag()) / denominator;
    return {real, imag};
}

template<typename Ty>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Complex<Ty>& num)
{
    return stream << num.real() << '+' << num.imag() << 'i';
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Complex<double> a(1.2, 2.25);
    Complex<int> b(2, -1);

    Complex<double> y = a / b;

    std::cout << y << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will definitely change to using the `static_assert` method, and the `_v` variant of `std::is_arithmetic` looks quite nice too.

My reasoning behind using encapsulation is because that's how how I typically see classes being implemented, from my experience it is not too common to directly access member variables, but I do agree that the code is significantly cleaner after just making the member variables public.

I didnt realize that they would be left unitiniailized with the default constructor, so I will explicitly define it to just initialize to 0s.

Comment: `requires` is the modern, more readable alternative to `std::enable_if`.  `static_assert()` is different, because it doesn't stop the function existing (which can be important with overloads).  For the template itself, the short form is even simpler (`template<arithmetic_type T>`) if you're willing to define the `arithmetic_type` concept yourself (it's not provided in standard library).

Comment: I believe, `const` references are redundant in the constructor. Probably, other references may be removed too because `Complex` wraps only two arithmetic variables.

Comment: @Mark, member functions `real()` and `imag()` are consistent with `std::complex`, so there's an argument for keeping the familiar interface.

Comment: @finlaymorrison Encapsulation is a very good thing. Hiding the nitty-gritty details of a class simplifies the code that uses that class. The point of the first two sections was to get you to think about how ill-chosen methods can break encapsulation and how to either fix it (the immutable class) or do without it (the struct). I prefer the immutable class version.

Comment: @TobySpeight That's true about `requires`. I wasn't sure what version of C++ OP was using, so I stuck with C++11 constructs. I think `static_assert` works here because it stops compilation on a bad type and prints a useful error message.

Comment: @TobySpeight I've read up on the `std::complex` interface, and that interface is slightly different from OP. The `const` get-value methods are `real()` and `imag()`, but the non-`const` set-value methods take arguments and return void: `real(double)` and `imag(double)`. This difference keeps more encapsulation than OP.

Answer (score 1):

`std::is_arithmetic<>` might be too restrictive.  This prevents making complex numbers of bignum types, for example.

It's probably a good idea to define a Concept that `requires` the arithmetic operations you want to support, and use that.  Something like (untested)

```
template<typename T>
concept arithmetic_for_complex =
    requires(T a, T b) {
        a + b;
        a * b;
        /* etc. */
    };

template<arithmetic_for_complex Ty>
class Complex;
```